# Allure report in Jenkins does not load and it shows the loading on browser

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, appium, allure

I have used allure report in my framework for reporting.

After completion of test scripts on Jenkins and clicking allure report icon, it does not load the reports it show loading.

Allure Jenkins Plugin version = **2.10**

Following is the Jenkins console output:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-test) on project com.fa.ipsy: There are test failures.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Please refer to /Users/Edu/jenkins/workspace/Appium_android/target for the individual test results.
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
[Appium_ipsy_mobile] $ /Users/Edu/jenkins/tools/ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation/1.4.23.HOTFIX1/bin/allure generate "/Users/Edu/jenkins/workspace/Appium_android/target/allure-results" "/Users/Edu/jenkins/workspace/Appium_android/allure4208353174449196512.tmp/environment" -o "/Users/Edu/jenkins/workspace/Appium_android/allure4208353174449196512.tmp/allure-report"
Report successfully generated to the directory </Users/Edu/jenkins/workspace/Appium_android/allure4208353174449196512.tmp/allure-report>. Use `allure report open` command to show the report.
Finished: FAILURE
```

[image: Allure HTML reprort]

Thank you for the Help

Answer (score 1):

The Issue is resolved now, we are able see the Allure HTML reports.

We have updated our [Allure](https://plugins.jenkins.io/allure-jenkins-plugin) Jenkins plugin Version **(2.10)** to **2.26.0**.

Thanks